# Store temporary database on local storage

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, local-storage

I'm writing an application which "should" work online, but it will have to work even offline (if internet is down or other problems).

It should store and read informations from a MongoDB database which should be available even offline (maybe using Local Storage?)

I'll use only Google Chrome (it will be a Chrome packaged app) so I can take advantage of the features offered by this platform.

Is there some tool to make an offline copy of the MongoDB database and sync it when the application goes online?

**NB:** I don't wanna use meteor because I'm working on windows, it's something completely new to learn and I'd prefer stay with Express.js and the usual Node.js features I already use.

Comment: Little bit "off-topic" to ask for tools. Not quite there yet for true "local storage" but there is a browser implementation for [nedb](https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb). It truly is "MongoDB lite" so don't expect every feature.

Comment: well I'm looking for some way to accomplish it.. not sure how to call it.. tool, workaround, framework, trick, dunno.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution using Minimongo, it's the same used by Meteor but it's packaged standalone to be used on plain node.js.

https://www.npmjs.org/package/minimongo

Answer (score -2):

You can use something like Remote Storage http://remotestorage.io/integrate/ and host your own storage on backend side and sync it with application.